# Generic Func needed to perform sorting of Entity Framework collection

Tags: entity-framework, linq, func

I have a grid with columns.  When the grid column header is selected I post/ajax to server with header selected to return x rows.

In the following code, RefNo is integer while ProposalSectionNumber is a string.

How to make a generic function taking a string but return a Func to be used in the linq statement?

```
if (sort.dir == SortDirection.Asc)
{
    switch (sort.field)
    {
        case "RefNo":
            qry = qry.OrderBy(x => x.RefNo);
            break;
        case "ProposalSectionNumber":
            qry = qry.OrderBy(x => x.ProposalSectionNumber);
            break;                     
    }
}
else
{
    switch (sort.field)
    {
        case "RefNo":
            qry = qry.OrderByDescending(x => x.RefNo);
            break;
        case "ProposalSectionNumber":
            qry = qry.OrderByDescending(x => x.ProposalSectionNumber);
            break;

    }
}
```

I would like to do something like 
string sortOrder = "RefNo"
var sortfunc = SortFunc(sortOrder)

```
if (sort.dir == SortDirection.Asc)
{
   qry = qry.OrderBy(sortFunc)
}
else
{
   qry = qry.OrderByDesc(sortFunc)
}
```

I have struggled creating the function SortFunc (which returns based on string or integer)

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Use the System.Linq.Dynamic nuget package, you can order by the property name as a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with declaring a type for `sortFunc` is that it depends on the type of the field by which you sort. If all fields were of the same type, say, all `string`s, you could use the type of `Expression<Func<MyEntity,string>>` for your `sortFunc` variable.

There is another way of removing code duplication when sort fields do not share a common type. Introduce a generic helper method that takes sort order as a parameter, and call it instead of `OrderBy`/`OrderByDescending`:

```
private static IOrderedQueryable<T> AddOrderBy<T,TKey>(
    IQueryable<T> orig
,   Expression<Func<T,TKey>> selector
,   bool isAscending
) {
    return isAscending ? orig.OrderBy(selector) : orig.OrderByDescending(selector);
}
```

Now you can rewrite your code as follows:

```
var isAscending = (sort.dir == SortDirection.Asc);
switch (sort.field) {
    case "RefNo":
        qry = qry.AddOrderBy(x => x.RefNo, isAscending);
        break;
    case "ProposalSectionNumber":
        qry = qry.AddOrderBy(x => x.ProposalSectionNumber, isAscending);
        break;                     
}
```